NextResponse.redirect() not redirecting to the desired route in NextJs Middleware for handling protected routes
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

export default async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  const publicPaths = ["/"]; //all public paths
  const path = req.nextUrl.pathname;
  const isPublicPath = publicPaths.includes(path);
  const token = req.cookies.get("access_token")?.value || "";

  if (isPublicPath && token) {
    const redirectPath = "/dashboard";
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(redirectPath, req.nextUrl));
  } else if (!isPublicPath && !token) {
    const loginPath = "/";
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(loginPath, req.nextUrl));
  }
  if (!isPublicPath && token) {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(validatTokenRoute, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
        next: {
          revalidate: 600,
        },
      });
      if (!response.ok) {
        // Invalid token, redirect to login
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/", req.nextUrl));
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error verifying token:", error);
      req.cookies.set("access_token", "");
      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/", req.nextUrl));
    }
    return NextResponse.next();
  }

  return NextResponse.next();
}
export const config = {
  matcher: ["/", "/dashboard/:path*"],
};

In the above code I am redirecting the user if the token is not valid its working when the token is valid but if its not valid the site keeps on loading infinitely and does not redirect to the correct url.
How can i redirect the user to "/" if the token is present but not a valid token.
